# Как сделать обводку в unity?

Tags: unity3d, графика, 3d

[image]

Как сделать похожую обводку, как на этой картинке? Сразу говорю это не текстура, а пост процессинг, но я не знаю как его сделать... 
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Это называется outline shader, в юнити такое вроде есть в нескольких вариантах из коробки. Но лучше так не делать.

Comment: Спасибо большое!